# Bigquery calculating values based on string column

Tags: google-bigquery, formula

I have this kind of table

```
Date  Cat1 Nominal
01/05 A    100
01/05 B    200
02/05 C    300
02/05 A    400
03/05 C    200
```

I need to calculate each 'Cat1' as formula with conditions where a row not found then it is considered '0'
And this is my expected table

```
Date  FormulaName Nominal
01/05 A-B+C       -100   
01/05 B/A         2
02/05 A-B+C       700
02/05 B/A         0
03/05 A-B+C       200
03/05 B/A         0
```

As you can see that at 01/05 C not found then considered '0' and same as B at 02/05.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT day, x.*
FROM (
  SELECT day, 
    IFNULL(MAX(IF(cat1 = 'A', nominal, NULL)), 0) AS A,
    IFNULL(MAX(IF(cat1 = 'B', nominal, NULL)), 0) AS B,
    IFNULL(MAX(IF(cat1 = 'C', nominal, NULL)), 0) AS C
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY day
), UNNEST([
  STRUCT('A - B + C' AS FormulaName, A - B + C AS nominal), 
  ('B / A', IFNULL(SAFE_DIVIDE(B, A), 0))
]) x
```

If to apply to sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '01/05' day, 'A' cat1, 100 nominal UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/05', 'B', 200 UNION ALL
  SELECT '02/05', 'C', 300 UNION ALL
  SELECT '02/05', 'A', 400 UNION ALL
  SELECT '03/05', 'C', 200 
)
SELECT day, x.*
FROM (
  SELECT day, 
    IFNULL(MAX(IF(cat1 = 'A', nominal, NULL)), 0) AS A,
    IFNULL(MAX(IF(cat1 = 'B', nominal, NULL)), 0) AS B,
    IFNULL(MAX(IF(cat1 = 'C', nominal, NULL)), 0) AS C
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY day
), UNNEST([
  STRUCT('A - B + C' AS FormulaName, A - B + C AS nominal), 
  ('B / A', IFNULL(SAFE_DIVIDE(B, A), 0))
]) x
```

result is

```
Row day     FormulaName nominal  
1   01/05   A - B + C   -100.0   
2   01/05   B / A       2.0  
3   02/05   A - B + C   700.0    
4   02/05   B / A       0.0  
5   03/05   A - B + C   200.0    
6   03/05   B / A       0.0
```

Comment: `('B / A', IFNULL(SAFE_DIVIDE(B, A), 0)` can i add this to another struct or add more formula?

Comment: sure, you can add as many formulas as you need - they should go inside `UNNEST([ ... ])`. There are two there as of now